# Distinct rows from a join

Tags: mysql, join, duplication

I have two MySQL tables:

```
╔═══════════════════╗
║ wpss_question_set ║
╠═══════════════════╣
║ id                ║
║ quesset           ║
╚═══════════════════╝

╔════════════════╗
║ wpss_questions ║
╠════════════════╣
║ id             ║
║ question       ║
║ ques_set_id    ║
╚════════════════╝
```

`ques_set_id` is the foreign key. The query is:

```
SELECT
    wpss_quesset.quesset,
    wpss_questions.*
FROM wpss_quesset
JOIN wpss_questions 
    ON wpss_quesset.id = wpss_questions.ques_set_id;
```

I am getting duplicate results on `ques_set_id` and `quesset`. How do I select unique records from '`ques_set_id` and `quesset`?

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Please ignore `type` and `quiz_id` columns. Answer considering it.

Comment: The result set of a SQL query is a table, a set of rows and columns. If some of the rows belong with one another based on certain criteria, some of the values *must* be repeated to indicate that. If you want to avoid the repetition in the output, then you are dealing with a *presentation* issue, which, accordingly, should be addressed at your presentation level (typically your application). If, however, you are positive that in this case you want the *query* to be your presentation level and return a result set already prepared for display, please tell/show us what the output should look like.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to select unique record from other join table which has same FK in multiple row you can use your query as

```
 SELECT
        wpss_quesset.quesset,
        wpss_questions.*
    FROM wpss_quesset
    JOIN wpss_questions 
        ON wpss_quesset.id = wpss_questions.ques_set_id
   GROUP BY wpss_quesset.id
```

OR If you want to get all record that of related FK you should use group concat with group by

Example

```
 SELECT
        wpss_quesset.quesset,
        GROUP_CONCAT( wpss_questions.question)
        wpss_questions.*
    FROM wpss_quesset
    JOIN wpss_questions 
        ON wpss_quesset.id = wpss_questions.ques_set_id
   GROUP BY wpss_quesset.id
```

Comment: I want to also randomize the results. Can i use `rand()` with `group by`?

Comment: Second query execute all the records in one field.How to produce randam single question from that?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from (SELECT
        wpss_quesset.quesset,
        GROUP_CONCAT( wpss_questions.question)
        wpss_questions.*
    FROM wpss_quesset
    JOIN wpss_questions 
        ON wpss_quesset.id = wpss_questions.ques_set_id
   GROUP BY wpss_quesset.id order by rand()) abc limit 1
```